# TP-Link low download speeds, normal upload speeds via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I bought a TP-link Archer C50 router (300Mbps 2.4GHz + 866Mbps 5GHz). When I connect my laptop directly to the router via cable, the download speed on Speedtest is as it should be (85Mbps). However when I connect via WiFi, no matter 2.4GHz or the 5GHz connection, the download speed can't get above 30Mpbs.

The weird thing is that the upload speed is the same on WiFi and wired connection (Speedtest shows 67Mbps). I tried upgrading the firmware to the latest version, but nothing changed. I tried all combinations of channels and widths on both connections, but see only minor differences.

I'm about 3 meters away from the router without any walls or objects between. Both connections use WPA2 encryption.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What kind of wireless interface does your laptop have?

Comment: Android phone?  Install wifi analyzer to see if you have signal issues? (3 meters means nothing if you're in a highrise in NY City where you literally could be within 3 meters of any one.. :) Signal issues suspected due to slower *wireless* speeds

One I've used:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en .. Its adware based like the rest, but so far hasn't been overt or obnoxious about it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My laptop adapter is http://ark.intel.com/products/75439/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260

Comment: @TG2 There isn't any other 5GHz in the region. The connection says: http://i.imgur.com/6HI0qvA.png